# (Python) How do I reverse characters of a list item

Tags: python, string, list, reverse

I want to reverse character order of every item in a list

I have `myList = ['78', '79', '7a']` and I want it to get the output `87 97 a7`

so far I've tried:

```py
newList = [x[::-1] for x in myList][::-1]
```

and

```py
def reverseWord(word):
    return word[::-1]

myList = ['78', '79', '7a']

newList = [reverseWord(word) for word in myList]
```

this would either return the original list or reverse the entire list and not just the items

Comment: `newList = [x[::-1] for x in myList]` is enough

Comment: Hi, do what's your expected output? One big string, print each value in a new line? For example, your first method looks almost corrrect.

Comment: Just remove the second `[::-1]` from the first code. It reverse the result list.

Comment: Then use `' '.join(x[::-1] for x in myList)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your line `[x[::-1] for x in myList][::-1]`, the final `[::-1]` does reverse the list, you don't need it

What you missing is only formatting : join the element using a space

```
myList = ['78', '79', '7a']
res = " ".join(x[::-1] for x in myList)
print(res)  # 87 97 a7
```

Comment: I just gave it a try but the output I get is `7 8   7 9   7 a`

Comment: @gtrix I didn't change any char in the solution ;)

Comment: ooh I think I see what went wrong, my list wasn't set up correctly and I had `78 79 7a` instead of `['78', '79', '7a']`

Answer (score 0):

Since your trying to reverse only the items inside the list and not the list it-self you only need to remove the extra `[::-1]`,so your code should look like this:

```
myList = ['78', '79', '7a']
newList = [x[::-1] for x in myList]
```

In addition your second code using the `reverseWord` method is correct and gives you exactly the output you wanted.

```
def reverseWord(word):
return word[::-1]

myList = ['78', '79', '7a']

newList = [reverseWord(word) for word in myList]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a one-liner to do the job :

```
newList = list(map(lambda x:''.join(reversed(x)), myList))
['87', '97', 'a7']
```